# convert timestamp to date in bash

Tags: bash

i have time logs in timestamp (epoch unix time) format :

```
1515365117236

1515365123162

1515365139963
```

i would like to convert it to a regular date like

```
2017-01-07 23:48:01

2017-01-07 23:48:02

2017-01-07 23:48:03
```

any ideas what approach would be the fastest?

```
cat ff1.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date -d +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ; done > somefile.csv
```

this takes awful lot of time and just appends the current time

Comment: Note that this question is useful because the OP gave timestamps with _milliseconds_. That means it's not really epoch unix time in its purest definition, but it is something that people will face a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach that must be much faster , using `printf` of `bash version >4.2` :

```
$ printf '%(datefmt)T\n' epoch
```

For `datefmt` you need a string accepted by `strftime(3)` - see `man 3 strftime`

Testing:

```
$ cat file10
1515365117236
1515365123162
1515365139963

$ printf '%(%F %H:%M:%S)T\n' $(cat file10)
49990-01-04 04:47:16
49990-01-04 06:26:02
49990-01-04 11:06:03
```

In this case , `printf` format string is:

> %F    Equivalent to %Y-%m-%d (the ISO 8601 date format). (C99)
>
> %H    The hour as a decimal number using a 24-hour clock (range 00 to 23).(Calculated from tm_hour.)
>
> %M    The minute as a decimal number (range 00 to 59).  (Calculated from tm_min.)
>
> %S    The  second  as  a decimal  number (range 00 to 60).  (The range is up to 60 to allow for occasional leap seconds.- Calculated from tm_sec.)

Update to remove milliseconds:

```
$ printf '%(%F %T)T\n' $(printf '%s/1000\n' $(<file10) |bc)
2018-01-08 00:45:17
2018-01-08 00:45:23
2018-01-08 00:45:39
```

Comment: `%H:%M:%S` can be shortened to `%T`.

Comment: @George many thanks for taking the time to look into this issue, I've converted my file to unix format with dos2unix but still I'm getting a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The way to transform epoch to date is `date -d @epochtime +format`

An alternative way is to use `date --file` switch to read dates from a file directly.

```
$ cat file10
1515365117236
1515365123162
1515365139963
```

In order `date` to understand that these lines are epoch time you need to add `@` in the beginning of each line.

This can be done like bellow:

```
$ sed -i 's/^/@/g' file10  #caution - this will make changes in your file
$ date --file file10 +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Alternativelly, you can do it on the fly without affecting the original file:

```
$ sed 's/^/@/g' file10 |date --file - +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

PS: in this case `--file` reads from `-` == `stdin` == pipe

In both cases, the result is

```
49990-01-04 04:47:16
49990-01-04 06:26:02
49990-01-04 11:06:03
```

PS: by the way, the timestamps you provide seems invalid, since it seems to refer at year 49990

Comment: The timestamps appear to include milliseconds. 1515365117236 is 2018-01-07 17:45:17.236 (EST).

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag in your sed commands. `^`, by definition, only appears once per line anyway.

Comment: any ideas how to convert it to proper date, without miliseconds included?

Answer (score 1):

Your input data aren't epoch unix time, it has miliseconds. If you wish to use any method on bash first you must convert to timestamp:

```
cat ff1.csv  | while read LINE; do echo "@$(expr $LINE \/ 1000)" | date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" --file - ;  done
```

First divide by 1000 to delete miliseconds parts, the rest is the same that explain George Vasiliou

Comment: Good catch with the milliseconds.